# AVAudioPlayer not playing without IVAR

Tags: ios, avfoundation

Before I learned about categories, I had a declared a method for my entity in the generated NSManagedObject Subclass:

```
// UserRecording.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface UserRecording : NSManagedObject {
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * dateCreated;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * audioData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;

-(void) URplay;

@end
```

and here's the implementation:

```
// UserRecording.m


#import "UserRecording.h"

@implementation UserRecording

@dynamic dateCreated;
@dynamic audioData;
@dynamic name;

-(void) URplay {
    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:self.audioData error:&error];
   [audioPlayer play];
}

@end
```

When I learned about categories (via the Stanford iTunes U videos), I moved the code to a category.  But the sound stopped playing.  The only difference was that there was no declared instance variable (IVAR).  Indeed I tested it in my old code.  The above code plays audio, but this code doesnt (in the Simulator):

```
// UserRecording.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface UserRecording : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * dateCreated;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * audioData;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;

-(void) URplay;

@end
```

and the implementation:

```
// UserRecording.m

#import "UserRecording.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@implementation UserRecording

@dynamic dateCreated;
@dynamic audioData;
@dynamic name;

-(void) URplay {
    NSError *error;
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:self.audioData error:&error];
   [audioPlayer play];
}

@end
```

Maybe it have something to do with ARC?  But regardless, what can I do?  You can't declare an instance variable in a category so that won't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm paraphrasing what I [learned](https://devforums.apple.com/message/695729) on the Apple Developer Forums:

Due to ARC, local variables will be deallocated when they leave scope.  So the AVAudioPlayer declared in the method will vanish before it gets a chance to play.  While adding an IVAR is possible in some contexts, here it isn't.  The reason is that you cannot add IVARs to categories. To elaborate, the above NSManagedObject subclass is generated by XCode - if I added an IVAR to the entity, it would get overwritten by XCode when I changed the entity & regenerated.

Therefore, the solution is to rethink where my persistent AVAudioPlayer should go.  I'll probably add a persistent AVAudioPlayer* as an argument to the category's method and pass it along when the method gets called.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with ARC in the sense that your AVAudioPlayer is getting deallocated right after you instantiate it, because with ARC local variables are deallocated when you leave the scope, try declaring a property for it, you don't need an ivar per se:

In header file or interface declaration in the implementation:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

In implementation:

```
@synthesize audioPlayer = _audioPlayer;
```

This last part implicitly creates an ivar `_audioPlayer` for your property. You can access it directly, but I'd suggest still going throw the setter `self.audioPlayer =`.

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned the goal is to put this in a Category. So I can't use property & synthesize (no IVARs).  And I can't edit the entity file because it'll get regenerated at some point and I'll lose my method. Turns out I'm going to need to rethink the design a bit as I'll need persistent AVAudioPlayer(s).

Comment: Sorry about that, all you need is something to hold the reference of your AVAudioPlayer, for instance, I see that your object just holds properties, and the audio player. How about simply removing the audio player from your object, setting it up in your controller and then using the audio data from your object to play it. Sounds more reasonable.

Comment: That's pretty much what I did (see below).  I just tested it and it works. In fact, I got rid of the category.  It was the wrong design - you can't `play` a recording, you can only `play` an AVAudioPlayer.